# jquery fadeOut() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a jquery problem and I can't figure out why it would be. Perhaps someone here could help me out.

Here is the jquery method that I have (just a simple, fadeOut()).

```
$("#aboutbtn").click(function(){
  $("#slideshowContainer").fadeOut();
});
```

Here are the button that I am working with and the div that I am working with.

```
<div id="slideshowContainer">
  <div class="slideshow"> 
      testing
  </div>
  <ul id="nav">
    <!--<li id="prev"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li id="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>-->
  </ul>
</div>

<a id="aboutbtn" class="menuitem" href="#">About</a>
```

When I click the About link, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things. Make sure you bind the event in the `document`'s `ready` handler (or at least after the element has been rendered), and make sure you prevent the default behavior of the link (which is to navigate the page to its `href`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#aboutbtn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#slideshowContainer").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/g6dzd/

In addition, the `id` of the elements must be unique, otherwise the jQuery selector will only match the first one and may not do what you expect because of it.

Also, if the link is dynamically added to page (like with AJAX), the event handler won't be bound properly like this, since the element can't be found. That's because, like I said in the beginning, the handler must be bound after the element has been rendered. So, you must bind the event to the new content, or probably more easily/efficiently, you can use event delegation. With this, you bind an event to a stable container element (one that is not dynamically added/removed), and delegate the handler to a specific selector. For example, something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#container_element_id").on("click", "#aboutbtn", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#slideshowContainer").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Sometimes, you can use `document` for this selector (instead of `#container_element_id`), but can usually be narrowed down.

Comment: Also might want to make sure there isn't more than one `aboutbtn` in the page and that the content isn't dynamically created after the page is loaded.

Comment: @jfriend00 I need to make a checklist of things that should be included in an answer, because too often does the OP not mention something that usually applies to one of the things we mentioned. It's probably easier to always include all. I'll update, thanks :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I had another element named aboutbtn. d'oh

Comment: @jfriend00 Haha you win, you were correct! I never would've thought of that. I guess I should more often

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#aboutbtn").click(function(){
    $("#slideshowContainer").fadeOut();
   })
});
```

you should write the code in document.ready or $(function(){});. other wise it won't work.